# Is it considered poor form to answer old and inactive questions? (thread resurrection)

Tags: discussion, etiquette, bump

I think the title says it all. On some support boards and forums it is considered poor form because it causes activity that bothers some. Especially to those that monitors that site's "newest changes" page.

The behavior is called "[thread resurrection](https://www.christianforums.com/threads/whats-wrong-with-thread-resurrection.8130445/)" (or "graveyard bumping") and there are even [memes](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/35l1gj) about it.

If different policies applies to different SE sites, please link to them in your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does it make sense to answer old questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23996/does-it-make-sense-to-answer-old-questions)

Comment: It is certainly not called “thread resurrection” around here. Although I imagine that name is a bit more appropriate in the Christian forum you link.

Comment: No, the idea on SE is to build a long last and evergreen library of knowledge. It’s encouraged to add fresh and updated (but actually fresh and updated! not new takes on old answers) answers to old questions, especially if those questions are high value, canonical, and have outdated answers. That said, on EL&U, necromancy tends to annoy me, because most such bumps being either boring questions or trivially new answers to the front page. Or perfectly good questions which are sufficiently answerer already and should be agreed to be “completed business”.

Comment: We even have a badge for it: [revival](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/126/revival)