# What is the Total Reputation field on Area51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase, total-reputation

What does the `total reputation` field on Area51 represent?  It's obviously not the total of the user's reputation on the various sites, as that is the number listed as `user reputation`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the total rep of the user and all the people that they've referred.

Click on it and see what you get:

[image: Not all total rep are equal :-)]

Comment: Does that mean that being referred counts double for achieving site goals? Once for the actual user, and once for the referrer?

Comment: @ccomet - no idea.

Comment: @ccomet no, it's just a way to show off that you got people to sign up

Comment: @David Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Hmmm, odd, the tooltip has changed from "... reputation across all sites" to just "reputation score".