# And just like that, I have 150k rep. Umm.. What?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, area-51

I just noticed this on the [Astronomy proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40709/astronomy?referrer=026lEiBQqabphaX8g_kypA2) on Area 51:

[image: (2 referred; 150k total rep) Undo 18.5k]

This is wrong on so many fronts:

1. I don't have anywhere near 150k network rep
2. It shows to other people (I've checked this) that I do
3. It cheats others out of their rightful place in the total reputation list.

I honestly don't know how/why it happened, but I do know I don't have 150k rep. About 30 minutes before it went to 150k, I noticed it was at 148k, if it helps anything.

As mizo pointed out in the comments, the 150k seems to be the combination of my rep + my two referred users:

> 125831 (Rory Alsop) + 5673 (RhysW) + 18472 (Undo) = 149976

Comment: That is weird...  I blame caching, just because.

Comment: I blame Jon Skeet. He's donated his rep to a charity which helps low rep users like this one.

Comment: @Robert I tried to blame caching for why the trash did not appear to be out on the curb yet. My wife didn't buy it, and she knows what caching is.

Comment: @Robert In all seriousness, is there any way this could be caching? It seems impossible, but I've seen stranger... Nope, this is the strangest.

Comment: @Undo not unless you just had some epic serial up voting reversed ;)

Comment: I would pay to watch that kind of serial up voting.

Comment: The detailed rep counts suggest that 150k is the sum of your rep and the rep of the two referred users: 125831 (Rory Alsop) + 5673 (RhysW) + 18472 (Undo) = 149976.

Comment: @mizo Nice find!

Comment: @mizo That's exactly what's going on, Area51 is weird.

Comment: I guess you could say you need to *Undo* your reputation. No? Nobody? Okay, I'll show myself out.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53691/what-is-the-total-reputation-field-on-area51, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118291/combined-reputation-on-area-51-is-higher-than-the-one-shown-in-stack-exchange-fl?lq=1, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54022/what-is-the-value-of-total-reputation-on-area-51?lq=1, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57767/total-rep-on-area-51-is-wrong-confusing?lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

As you can see in your screenshot, on Area51 there are two tabs, one for user reputation, one for total reputation.

User reputation shows what you probably expect it would: the sum of your reps across Stack Exchange.

Part of the Area51 process is about getting experienced Stack Exchange posters to commit to good new proposals. So when experienced posters follow **your** referral link to commit to a proposal, you get some credit for it, to incentivise you to lure them in. That credit appears in the total reputation table, which is [the sum of your reps, plus all the reps of posters you referred to the proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53692/164022). Click on a "total rep" square to see the reps of all the people that that poster has referred, and got credit for.

The only place that has any effect, is the total reputation league. It's just another number on a database to incentivise constructive behaviour. The number also appears in the user league, where it's labelled "total reputation", to distinguish it from "user reputation"

Comment: Hmm.. Seems weird. Have any official sources for that?

Comment: @Undo http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53691/what-is-the-total-reputation-field-on-area51

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder if there is a proposal I could get Jon Skeet to commit to via referral. Perhaps a site focused on topics related to the awesomeness of Jon Skeet?

Comment: @Undo tooltip for the total rep tab.