# Total Rep on Area 51 is wrong/confusing

Tags: support, reputation, area-51, total-reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Total Reputation field on Area51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53691/what-is-the-total-reputation-field-on-area51)

If you go to [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) you can see my name under 6th in the list of committed users.  It says I have 9 referred and 9k total rep, but under my name it has 3,216 for my reputation... which seems to be the correct figure for my combined total reputation across all S.E. sites.

So where does the 9k come from?

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53691/what-is-the-total-reputation-field-on-area51/53692#53692), it is the combined rep of all the people you've referred.  but clicking the 9k brings up all 9 people I've referred and it seems to be significantly less than 9k.

Comment: To quote ChrisF on your linked question, "It's the total rep of the user and all the people that they've referred". 9159 = 3216 + 5943 = 3216 + (2297 + 1413 + 1280 + 641 + 107 + 51 + 51 + 51 + 51 + 1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That answer actually says it is the total rep of the user *and* all of the people they've referred. The total is correct if you are including your own reputation.

Answer (score 4):

The combined rep is the rep of all the people you've referred *plus your rep*. I just did the math and it comes out to 9159.