# Best way to find out my total rep for all sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I was looking on the Area 51 site, and I can see my total rep *for all sites* by looking at a proposal I'm committed to, but it's not anywhere on my profile. Is there a better way to find out what my total rep is?

Comment: Just in case you're referring to the square that says "total rep": that might be different than you think. See [What is the Total Reputation field on Area51?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53691/what-is-the-total-reputation-field-on-area51/53692#53692)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [**app created by George Edison**](https://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-for-everything-stackexchange) for just this.

[**Take a look here.**](http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com/display.php). You can bring up your rep for each site and look at it separately, or you can see your total rep for all properly associated sites.

For example here is your total rep, total graph, and assorted other:
[image]

Comment: Oh *damn*. Your screenshot illustrates perfectly that now, even if you quit programming, there will always be at least one other Stack Exchange site for you. You can check out, but you can never leave....

Answer (score 2):

If you go here

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134686?tab=accounts#tab-top

it will display all of you accounts but it doesn't show the overall total rep as a single figure - I think you'll have to get your calculator out.

Might be worth raising a feature request and ask to get it added on to this page.

Comment: Note that the most complete listing will be at the Area 51 user page, since that also lists private betas (and Area 51 rep itself).

Answer (score 1):

There should be a service for that.