# Feature Request: Add Total Rep to the user profile on Area 51

Tags: feature-request, reputation, area-51

based on [This Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63243/best-way-to-find-out-my-total-rep) I asked. I think it'd be nice to have an easy way to view a users total rep.

Answer (score 6):

I would also like to see this on the main Stack Exchange site.