# How is commitment progress calculated?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Area 51 Commit Percent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent)

I can't understand how is commitment progress calculated for area51 proposed websites. E.g. persian IT q&a site (at the time of writing this question) has 130 persons committed, although progress is barely 3% while Apple has only 55 persons committed and the progress is almost 8 times bigger?