# Commit percentage formula update?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase

Hi,
  In an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650), David Fullerton sketched out a formula by which commit progress is calculated for area51 proposals, and mentioned that the formula would undergo updates over time as the SE overlords monitored proposals in beta and saw how they evolved.

I was wondering whether such updates were happening already, or if there was one planned? I'm personally interested because I'm monitoring the status of the Theoretical Computer Science proposal, and am trying to get a sense of how much longer it's likely to take to reach 100%, based on current commit rates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been 1 or 2 tweaks to the commitment % formula in the last month.

Nothing *major*, but the thrust of it was to slightly increase the commitment "power" of new users while slightly decreasing the same for existing network users.

(David would have to add more detail.)

Overall we feel the commitment % is working pretty much as designed, though -- so get out there and promote your proposal by sharing the URL and sharing commitment referral URLs!