# Can we please see the breakdown to the Area 51 commit formula?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, commitment-phase

Assuming [Jeff still believes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59712/commit-percentage-formula-update/59744#59744) that

> Overall we feel the commitment % is
>   working pretty much as designed...

Would it be possible to show the details of the commit formula? This would be nice to see broken up into the goals of each category [David explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733):

> 1. A total Commitment Score of 500,
> 2. 200 committers
> 3. 100 committers with at least 200 rep on a single site

Perhaps this could be a mouseover the main commit % on the commitment page?

Comment: You mean you want a breakdown of how far a proposal is in each category, instead of a combined commit percentage?

Comment: @Michael: A way to see the breakdown, yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to keep the details about how the commit score is calculated at least *somewhat* obscured.

I know it can be frustrating not to know *exactly* what you need to push your proposal over the finish line, but we want users to focus on attracting broad, organic support for the site — Not to optimize their behavior just to make the numbers work in their favor.

The commit numbers are not an exact science. They simply measure and reflect some statistical approximations of what kind of users we need to make a site succeed. If you optimize the type of users you solicit just to hit those numbers, you are much more likely to generate false positives… and that will not be good for the site.