# Include Area 51 reputation in your weight of commitment

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, area-51, commitment-phase

Area 51 reputation does not count towards your weight in the commitment percentage.

Would you consider changing that?

Right now reputation in that site isn't good for much, but this could give it a little more meaning -- In my opinion if you have high reputation you either had good sites ideas, or you participated a lot in the definition phase for them; this "work" should count towards something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Area 51 reputation is not included, because we want users to have contributed real knowledge to a real Q&A site.

Comment: +1. I agree with @Juan that A51 rep should count towards _something_, but this isn't it.

Answer (score -1):

I would **love** to have this (because I would like to give my proposal a boost). But I don't think it is a good idea to mix proposal status with individual rep. They are two different things. "Success" (for want of a better word) of an individual, measured in rep, is independent of the success of any proposal.

Comment: What are you talking about? I'm not proposing anything weird -- right now what currently counts is your total reputation from all sites *except* area 51, I want that site to be added to the formula.

Comment: @Juan - perhaps we're talking about different things. I thought you meant commitment of a proposal, i.e. it's **progress**. Apparently I misunderstood. What do you mean by *commitment*?

Comment: I'm talking about commitment as you understood it -- I don't think you know how that progress is calculated though, see my first comment.

Comment: @Juan - you're right. I thought the progress of a proposal was calculated based on number of on/off topic questions + number of followers in the **define** phase and then number of followers in the **commit** phase. Is that not correct?

Comment: Each user weights differently based on his total reputations from all sites except area 51

Comment: @Juan: You mean the "weight" of each user affects the level of commitment? Can you link to documentation about this? Why? I don't get the logic of that at all.

Comment: @Mark: Commitments from high rep. users gets you faster through the stage than from low rep. users.  The idea is that you need high rep. users to establish the social norms in the beta stage.

Comment: @Mark: ["documentation"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53650/146482)

Comment: @Charles, @Tobias - thank you both. I had no idea that was the case...