# Where can I see someone's accept rate?

Tags: support, accept-rate

Where can I see someone's accept rate?

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for meta.stackoverflow.com...

Answer (score 3):

A user's accept rate is found in their signature block on one of their non-community-wiki questions.

However, there are some conditions under which it will *not* appear:

- The user has asked less than 4 qualifying questions (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work) for full details of what qualifies)
- The site is a per-site Meta (except Meta Stack Overflow (this site)) ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66774/is-it-bad-etiquette-to-have-a-0-accept-rate-on-meta-stackexchange-sites/67082#67082))
- The user is unregistered

Answer (score 1):

If you look on a question you've asked you will see your accept rate (57%) on the 2nd line below your name, right under your rep score. That's where everyone else's shows, btw.

```
Alan
50 [4 bronze badges]
57% accept rate
```