# Why isn't the accept rate being shown for all users on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

I noticed that there is no accept rate for all users in Meta Stack Overflow why?

But I can accept answers for my questions.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70828/163868

Comment: Which users? I'm seeing it on my questions - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/is-there-any-analytics-information-that-moderators-can-access-for-individual-que and one of Sathya's - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96000/suggested-edits-review-page-shows-the-user-who-proposed-the-edit-as-anonymous-us - for example.

Comment: @Sathya The OP asks why accept rate is not shown on MSO. The premise for this question, that it is the case that accept rate is not shown on MSO, is false. Believing that premise may be due to only looking at questions by users who do not satisfy the conditions for having accept rate shown and those conditions are explained by http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70828/163868. Thus, I think the link answer what the OP asks.

Comment: @Sathya: Please don't make edits that change the meaning of OP's questions, thus invalidating existing answers. Padma did originally ask about *his* questions. Incidentally, Chris' answer does explain well enough whichever way the question was phrased.

Comment: @GoranJovic If you see the first revision - the question was about **all users**. " `I noticed that there is no accept rate for all users`" I've been editing long enough to know when, how & what to change

Comment: @Sathya: In that case, I have no idea what you meant by `that doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking for`, because the linked answer is about *any* user, i.e. all users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have only asked 3 questions here.

Accept rate only shows up on your profile in questions when you have 4 (or more) questions with 1 (or more) answer.

It never shows up on your profile in answers.

Comment: the user is asking why isn't it being shown for all. cursory glance indicates that it indeed isn't being shown

Comment: @Sathya - I'm seeing it on my questions.

Comment: @PadmaKumar - That's because it's not shown for people who have less than 4 questions.

Comment: I can't see it on yours - http://i.imgur.com/NPraw.png Marc's http://i.imgur.com/kvFQm.png Mine http://i.imgur.com/uQxNY.png Jarrod's

Comment: @Sathya that is answer? it is showing only in questions.

Comment: That not answering thing is working out well for your Meta rep

Comment: @Sathya I think it's only intended to show below you're avatar on questions.  So your screenshots are not valid arguments.

Comment: @random yeah - I couldn't help myself.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Except that they aren't all from answers.

Comment: @Sathya All three of the screenshots linked in your comment are answers (although it looks like you were trying to include a fourth screenshot that didn't make it)