# Is reputation from Area 51 counted towards the commitment score?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase

According to the [updated commitment formula system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733), the percentage is taken as the minimum of 3 factors:

1. Total Commitment Score / 500
2. Total # of committers / 200
3. Total # of committers with 200+ rep on a single site / 100

I have tried to audit this with [Persian Information Technology and Computer](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912), and the numbers I have got are:

1. 268.442750731 / 500 = 53%
2. 162 / 200  = 81%
3. 12 / 100 = 12%

Clearly the limiting factor is #3, the number of "200+ rep commiters". The percentage should be 12%, but it is listed as 8% on the page!

So I wonder where is the missing 4%? It turns out there are exactly 4 users committed to PITC that only has 200+ reps on Area 51. This strongly suggests that Area 51 is not one of the "single sites" in #3. Is it the case? If yes, why is Area 51 excluded?

(The same thing happens for [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics) where the percentage should be 87% instead of 82%. But Area-51-only users just account for 3%, I'm still wondering where is the missing 2%.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include Area 51 reputation in your weight of commitment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66236/include-area-51-reputation-in-your-weight-of-commitment)

Comment: Looks like I can still make a question to CW by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Area 51 reputation is not counted, because we want users to have contributed real knowledge to a real Q&A site, not just Area 51.

Comment: You *could* count it if the user has high rep in other sites...

Answer (score 0):

It is not counted.

Support [this feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66236/include-area-51-reputation-in-your-weight-of-commitment)