# Include number of fulfilled commitments in the commitment score of a proposal

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51

It has already been several times discussed how it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) that [Area 51 reputation is not taken into account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66924/is-reputation-from-area-51-counted-towards-the-commitment-score) for the commitment score

But it would perhaps make sense to include in the formula (if it is not already, I was not exactly sure) the number of fulfilled commitments as recorded in Area 51. I believe including this would give a good idea of the number of committers likely to fulfill their commitment for this particular proposal.

However, I do not find this essential, just a refinement of the existing system. And I expect other people might find that it is already accounted for by the reputation they will have gained by participating actively in the previous proposal.

Comment: This may begin to make more sense now that we've had several sites go all the way through the various phases. In the beginning, this wouldn't have been very informative, as there wouldn't have been *any* users that had fulfilled commitments.