# SO family reputation not updated on Area 51

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, area-51

When I joined Area 51, I was only on SO. After a while, I started using a few other sites, like this one (Meta), Programmers and others.

Even though my accounts are associated (I see every flair in Area 51) my reputation has not added up... it only shows the sum of Area51 + SO.

Is that the way it's supposed to work? I already cleared my associations and sis again with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Associated accounts only show up if you have more than 200 rep. Your SO and Area 51 accounts are the only ones that meet that.

Comment: This is correct

Comment: yeap, here's the explanation http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent