# What is the relationship between UserScore and commit percentage - how "cost effective" is it to work on increasing rep on other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase, commitment

There is a [formula for calculating a UserScore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733) which is apparently used when determining the commit percentage for a site in commitment stage.

However, the formula given there doesn't seem to correlate with what I'm seeing on the [3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-techniques-and-software?referrer=fdAQ9wFBFTolaRLwFFF1-A2) proposal - where the percentage seems to be based purely on numbers:  17 users / 200 = 0.085 -> 8% ?

[Ten of those committed users are medium & high rep](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022?phase=commitment&committers=totalreputation#tab-top), only seven below the 200 rep level.

Shouldn't someone with over 1k rep contribute more than 0.5% towards a proposal?

How do the scores calculated from the formula David posted convert to commit percentage?

Is there any point in demonstrating commitment by increasing rep on other sites? Or would it be better use of time to focus purely on the numbers and encourage other 3D artists to sign up, even if that brings down the average total rep?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so there's now updated criteria and formula in the first linked post.

To reach beta you must have at least 200 committers, of which 100 must have over 200 rep on any single Stack Exchange site, and a UserScore of 500 or more, based on this new formula:

```
UserScore = SUM(Reputation >= 200 ? 0.233 * ln(Reputation-101) - 0.75 : 0) + 1.5
```

The progress percentage will *never* go above UserCount/200 - and may infact be lower if there are not enough users with greater than 200 single-site rep (or too low a UserScore value).

So, the primary focus for getting a site into Beta seems to be somehow finding at least a hundred existing StackExchange users to join - something that relies on people stumbling across Area51, Meta, or a related blog post, since there's no way to promote or discuss proposals where people might see it.

After that, it's not immediately clear which is more important in terms of UserScore vs numbers - I'll have to do some calculations to work it out. *(will update this answer when I've done that)*

Comment: Peter: David Fullterton said "100 committers with at least 200 rep on A single site", and you are saying "on ANY". Really hope Davids answere is the right one :-)

Comment: We're both saying the same thing - I wrote "on any single Stack Exchange site", which I used since "on a single Stack Exchange site" could potentially imply that a specific site be nominated, as opposed to it being automatic.  I'll see if I can come up with a clearer way of wording it when I edit it later on.