# How much score a proposal has to accumulate in order to reach 100% of commitment in area51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase

[This Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent)  states how a single UserScore is calculated but it doesn't state how much of that has to be accumulated to reach 100%.

Comment: Related to a larger question I posted earlier today: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66777/what-is-the-relationship-between-userscore-and-commit-percentage ( though no answers yet :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the linked post to include that information.