# Who is really adding value to an area51 project in commitment phase

Tags: feature-request, area-51, commitment-phase

I know there's a [whole system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent) for calculating the commitment in an Area51 projects.

But wouldn't be great to know who is adding value or how much of the commitment status is added by me?

eg: in the [Genexus proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19860/genexus) we have over 170 people commited (most of them newbies) and we're only 5% thru

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the complexity of calculation the only way for you personally to affect the commitment level is through `UserScore`. Since its total value is 500 you could calculate what your personal contribution is.

Comment: I guess you are right... but still, the Area51 site could do the math for me and show me how I am contributing to the proposal

Comment: @sebastian: note, that you have too many low rep users committed. They really need to work on the amount of their rep, otherwise you never get to beta.