# How come a commitment can go down?

Tags: discussion, area-51

We are promoting the [Genexus Q&A](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19860/genexus) site... and last friday we were at 10% with 260 committers, and suring the same day we went down to 9% :(

First I tought it might have been a bug or something and that it would come back up in a while. Today, we have one more committer and commitment status is still 9%, how can that be?

Comment: Commiter can uncommit to the proposal, are you sure no one uncommited during that period ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Area 51 Commit Percent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent)

Comment: @Hox, I am positive about that...

Comment: @waiwai, I know how it works... I'm guessing something got wrong :(

Comment: @seb A user probably just lost enough rep to cause the % to be rounded down instead of up (i.e. the site is probably hovering around 9.5%).

Comment: thanks @waiwai, that make sense