# Strange increase commitment score

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment

During the last hour the commitment score for [game of go](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942?phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top) increased from 90% to 94%.

- First it went from 90% to 92% without anybody signing up
- Then it went from 92% to 94% with only two signups (51 rep each) which should only account for a 0.6% point increase.

It seems to be connected to the reminder mail sent out 2h ago.

Are there some weird caching issues at work here? Does the contribution of each committer (which depends on his rep) only get updated when he visits Area51?

For reference the commitment score formula: [Area 51 Commit Percent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733)

This question might be related, but I don't have enough meta rep to view it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54217/are-area-51-proposals-capped-at-90-commitment-currently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commitment score is reduced slightly over time, [it is set back to the original value when you visit the proposal page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97362/refresh-area-51-commitment-when-user-visits-proposal-site). This is a pretty recent change, previously you had to uncommit and recommit to achieve the same effect.

If a lot of high reputation users visit the site in a short time it could cause the commitment score to increase like that.

Comment: Looks like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733 is out of date then.