# Does the referral bonus still count in Area 51 if you re-commit?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase, referrals

So, commitment score slowly decreases with time. In addition, a person can gain reputation if they refer someone. So, what happens if I un-commit a proposal, and then re-commit, as far as the people referred to the project? Do I still get the benefits if they follow through on their commitment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to uncommit and recommit to refresh your commitment score on a proposal. [You only need to visit the commitment screen on Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108809/164022), and that renews your commitment score and undoes all your commitmnent decay..