# Do you do anything with the proficiency level given when committing?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase

Since March 8<sup>th</sup>, when you commit to a proposal on Area51, it asks you how well you know the topic (Professional or Expert, Academic or Research-Level Student, Merely Curious, etc.).

Is that information now used by [the formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent) determining a proposal's completion level (for example, giving lesser importance to the commitment of the merely curious and the beginners) or is it just there collecting information for now until you decide to do something with it at a later point?

Comment: +1, I've been too busy lately to even notice that feature crept in. I also wonder how it might affect fulfilling a commitment.

Comment: @TimPost: To my knowledge, it hasn't been mentioned on meta before this post. Unless you committed to a proposal between March 8th and now, you couldn't have heard of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are just collecting data for now.  In a few weeks or months we'll go through and see whether it's actually a good predictor of the success of a site.

Comment: Now, almost 4 years later, had this changed? Is that data just collected or it influences the proposal commitment score somehow?