# What do the commiter roles mean?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you do anything with the proficiency level given when committing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83897/do-you-do-anything-with-the-proficiency-level-given-when-committing)

I've just noticed that Area51 got a new interface element: commitment roles. Committed users are divided into "experts", "beginners", "enthusiasts", "curious", "academic", and possibly other categories.

So, what does it mean? Does it have something to do with how much "percentage weight" does a particular user's commitment hold?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, [nothing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83897/do-you-do-anything-with-the-proficiency-level-given-when-committing).