# area51 commit requirements biased too heavily towards overlap w/ existing sites?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase

Just read [this metaSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent) to find out what is required to launch a site:

> Put another way, every proposal that
>   launches must satisfy these three
>   criteria:
>
> ```
> A total Commitment Score of 500,
> 200 committers
> 100 committers with at least 200 rep on a single site
> ```

I question the 3rd of these. This requires a large number of committers who are already active on another StackExchange site. If there's an overlap in "user correlation" with computer programming (subjects likely to be of interest to computer programmers e.g. science fiction or gaming or mathematics), there is a huge bias towards success, as compared to something that is completely different (natural science or religion or something).

I don't think this is fair and I think you should reconsider it (well, definitely reconsider the requirement of *100* experienced committers, I could see requiring 10 or 20). Or at least make it *extremely* obvious to people who are interested in starting a site that they need to go out and get reputation on existing StackExchange sites, otherwise the "commit" vote they made doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 5):

Historical analysis has shown that users who are active in one Stack Exchange site are vastly more likely to actually follow through on their commitment (by a factor of 5 to 1) than users who are new to Stack Exchange. These new users are almost always committing because someone on the Internet told them to go to Area 51 and click "commit," not because they would actually participate in a Stack Exchange.

If we were to treat all committers as equal, we would end up opening a lot of sites that failed instantly due to lack of participation.

That does mean that newly created sites tend to strongly overlap with the topics that programmers are interested in. This effect will probably wear off in about six months as we gain more non-programmers on sites like cooking, photography, parenting, etc.

Comment: Plus, experienced users are vital in starting a new site because they know how Stack Exchange works.  Without enough of these users, a beta can quickly go off track.

Comment: @David: That makes complete sense. But requiring 100 of them?!!

Comment: @Jason By requiring 100 of them to sign up, you're more likely to get the 20 or 30 you need to set the base of the site. And honestly, the commitment score is significantly more challenging. Of the current top 10 proposals, only 3 of them do not have commitment score as their lowest requirement met, and one of those is tied for total committers.