# Area51 Commitment Progress Bars

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51

Could we have 3 progress bars right underneath that huge percentage (19%) on the right of [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4105/lego-mindstorms-robotics?referrer=pOQYUnoptyd3hJ0vc5L2Fg2)? Each of the progress bars could represent [the minimum requirements for beta launch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733):

> 1. A total Commitment Score of 500,
> 2. 200 committers
> 3. 100 committers with at least 200 rep
>      on a single site

A rollover onto one of these bars would show what it means. (i.e. Progress Bar 1 shows "This site has 42 commitment score of 500")

---

Furthermore, could we have a "[user score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733)" in the user's Area51 profile?

Comment: This is more or less planned, though graphically it may not be progress bars

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can now click "more info" beneath the commitment score to see a breakdown of the factors comprising it, for example:

[image]