# Changing Role/Interest for an Area51 proposal

Tags: support, area-51

I recently committed to an Area51 proposal, and by mistake I selected "Professional or Expert" instead of "Academic or Research-Level Student" as my primary Role/Interest. Is there a way to change this, other than uncommitting and then re-committing?

Comment: Is un-committing and re-committing a problem though (i.e. does it reset some other data)?

Comment: @Pekka's I don't know, I'm just a little hesitant: currently I can only commit to one more proposal, and I'm not sure whether that will change after uncommitting...

Comment: I don't think there are any consequences to doing it, but I agree it's a bit awkward and one might be hesitant to do it (also being unsure whether committing and uncommitting reduces the number of available commit tokens [which it doesn't]).

Comment: Sure, you could graduate from your academic institution and... Oh, or did you mean change your status on the site?

Comment: [Apparently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733) uncommitting and recommitting is even a recommended practice in some situations, so I'll go with it. Still looking for answers though, out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit way to change your "role" selection. Un-committing and then re-committing is the best way to make another selection.

There should be no side effects by doing this. Your commitment isn't "locked in" until the site gets created. Up until that point, you can change your committments around as you please.