# why such a large commitment score on Area51 for a proposal with only five eligible committers?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

The [Roblox](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4300/roblox?referrer=jZjmfvUnHybNMSeNOH-I8g2) proposal on Area51 has a component commitment score of **42%** (though an overall commit score of only 5%, owing to having only 5 committed followers who have scored more than 200 on SE sites other than Area51). Click on the "more info" at the bottom of the blue panel in the top-right corner to see the commitment component scores.

The calculation of the [component commitment score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53733/164022) is apparently:

UserScore = 
`SUM(Reputation >= 200 ? 0.233 * ln(Reputation-101) - 0.75 : 0) + 1.5`

How can those 5 users have amassed enough commitment points to bring the Roblox component commitment score to 42%?

Comment: This is a topic for http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com; use the "area51-meta" tag, and you are set to go. [This is](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/strange-text-when-i-share-an-area-51-site-on-facebook) an example of question you can ask there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula applies to *all* committers, not just the 5 with reputation over 200. Further, the `SUM` represents the sum of scores for each of the sites a committer with 200+ rep participates on. So, all committers except five would contribute "1.5" to the commitment score and the rest would have a variable contribution depending on their rep across the sites they participate on.

I haven't run the numbers, but it seems plausible that you'd arrive at 42% after considering all of the committers to the proposal. (There's also the commitment decay to account for, but that'd bring the number down, if anything.)

Comment: Assuming the stated formula is correct, only 5 users (the 5 with scores equal to or greater than 200 on any site) would have a non- constant "UserScore" (`(Reputation >= 200 ? <calc> : 0) + 1.5`). The sheer number of committers could account for the relatively high commitment score.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Yeah, you're right - only the 200+ five would have contributed something other than 1.5 to the score. I'll make that clearer in the answer.