# What are the requirement to launch a stackexchange Q&A

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal, commitment-phase, definition-phase

I want to launch a stackexchange forum for a specific area of expertise. Unfortunately the audience is quite limited (one reason is that I need the forum to be in french).

I would like to see what are the requirement for every step from definition to public (for now I just can see that I need 60 followers and 40 questions with a score of ten or more).

I will need to invest time to go from step to step and I don't want to end up with a last step where I need 5000 users with 300+ reputation...

No precise information is available on the FAQ nor in this meta. Can someone sum up the step?

Answer (score 3):

The number you quote are to get the site from the Proposal Stage to the Commitment stage.

To launch into beta you need to get to 100% commitment

The commitment score is the minimum of three scores:

- at least 200 committers in total
- at least 100 committers with 200+ rep on any other site
- 100% commitment score, based on committers' activity on all other sites and how old the commitment is.

The last on the list is the most important and the calculations can be found in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733)