# Accepting old answers

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period)
>   [Community vote for “Accepted Answer” (Rep. >= 5000 only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/community-vote-for-accepted-answer-rep-5000-only)
>   [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)

I know it's been around in several versions - but there are a lot of old questions, with answers, the user who asked them is now serving burgers in MacDonalds or something like that, but not programming, and haven't used SO for 3 years.

Shouldn't there be a way for moderators, or lets say someone with more than 5K rep (I know...) to mark those answers as accepted (as long as they are clearly the right ones...)

It can be a mechanism like the close voting - but accept voting, if 3 people decide to accept an answer - it will be accepted.

and you can give rep and or badges for those cleaners, to encourage analyzing old Q & A and deciding if one of the answers - answers the Question.

Just an idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of at least one of these: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26639/allow-users-to-mark-accepted-answer-on-someone-elses-question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/community-vote-for-accepted-answer-rep-5000-only

Comment: I honestly think this would be a bad idea because it would lead to subtle inaccuracies (it's very hard to be the judge on a broad range of topics to whether the answer is indeed correct and complete). It's easy to be thinking an answer sounds fine, though, so one might be tempted too easily to accept it (for another person)...

Comment: @ChristopheD - if the users is long gone, it would be the "most" accurate option. @jon - You are right... haven't found them on first search, but I've figured out someone already had raised those issues.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the highest voted answer enough?

The point of Q&A is to get an answer. The highest voted is going to be the first thing you'll try and if it works, you'll vote it up for the next person who finds that question in search for an answer.

---

EDIT: @Jonathan Sampson has a few answers of a similar ilk:

- [Would it be possible to have a "community accepted" feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature/3672#3672)
- [Community vote for "Accepted Answer" (Rep. >= 5000 only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/community-vote-for-accepted-answer-rep-5000-only/8603#8603)

and makes the good point, that the highest voted can sometimes be better than the accepted.

Comment: This is one solution, but sometimes all answers has same scores/ no scores at all. hence we need some tool to clear them up from the un-answered tab... since there were a lot of discussions about it already, moderators closed this thread...