# Allow users to accept answers on questions they didn't ask

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)
>   [Accepting old answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74487/accepting-old-answers)

With the recent changes on SO about reviewing first posts I changed my habits of how I use that feature. Since then I noticed that there are decent number of such posts that are answers where the questioner found the answer himself/herself, but the questioner didn't accept that answer.

While this alone is not a problem, these questions reappear in the Unanswered-category over and over again. IMHO they don't make much sense there.

Yes, there are some ideas how to make new users accept their answers, but that doesn't seem to be the final remedy.

In order to circumvent this, I thought about ways to solve this in general. Here are some ideas:

1. Add an option to the Flag-pop-up to mark an answer as an acceptable answer. This is available to all users who can review posts. If an answer has e.g. three such votes it gets accepted.
2. Allow users to directly accept an answer. This obviously requires a high-ranked privilege.

The minimum criteria for both are that there is no answer yet on that question and the option is only available on answers posted by the questioner.

*This idea is somewhat based on the fact that users write answers to their own question if they found the answer or they should have edited the question instead (flagable as such already).*

---

EDIT: some answers based on https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3Amyself+&submit=search (I tried to combine it with `hasaccepted:0` but that doesn't seem to be supported):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582717/483113
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5527843/483113
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4545515/483113 (questioner has 3k+ points)
- :

Comment: Link to sample questions where this would apply.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the answer is acceptable, then it's surely worthy of an upvote. A question with an upvoted answer doesn't count as unanswered anymore.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that.