# would like a way to mark an answer if useful question is abandoned by author

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow users to mark “accepted” answer on someone else's question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26639/allow-users-to-mark-accepted-answer-on-someone-elses-question)

Scenario is just now I googled/found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi) and it seems to me, given the number of upvotes on the question and the one and only answer, that it should be marked.  It's not that I care about the authors points, but more that I like to see the quality of SO as wiki/kb resource to programmers like me who get alot of use from it be as high as possible so it is successful as possible and thus stays around.

--> this is clearly not a big thing, but seeing the green checkbox when I arrive at a SO question makes the experience better for me.  I think it makes me feel that someone who knows more about the topic at hand than I do has "signed off" of the answer being valid.

Comment: If you read the comments, it appears that the answer isn't complete.

More importantly, `Accepted Answer` status is determined by the OP as solving his problem or answering his question.  How would we know if it actually did that.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the "accept" mark is to indicate that the answer was the one that was most useful to the question author; having anyone else check that mark would short-circuit that. Answers can continue to be added after an answer is accepted. Checking an answer as the accepted answer is more of a courtesy than anything else.

Also, we already have a far more powerful metric to indicate which answer was more useful generally, and that's the number of upvotes. Please note that when answers are sorted by votes (the default view, I believe), the accepted answer does *not* float to the top if it's not the top-voted answer.

In summary, I think this would be a bad idea.

Comment: just my two cents (not trying to actually argue) - i think the visual power of a green checkmark transcends it's, per documented, purpose