# How to flag users with many unaccepted answers on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, flags, accepted-answer

While using Stack Overflow, I have seen many users who post their questions and do not accept answers after getting correct answers.

Is there any way to flag such users?

I am not asking for a *Force accepted-answer flag* here, that's an entirely different perspective. The marked duplicate question has proposed an automatic procedure for forcefully accepting answers to questions that have been answered but do not have accepted answers.

Here, I am just asking if there is any way to flag such users who have high ratio of un-accepted answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force accepted-answer flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102315/force-accepted-answer-flag)

Comment: I appreciate your quick response, but that question is very different from what I am trying to ask here.

Comment: just leave a comment to accept an answer if he found any answer helpful.

Comment: I can currently leave a comment and i already know about this, But the Question here my friend is `Is there any way to flag such users ? `

Comment: There is no way to flag a specific user. But if there were, what would you expect to happen as a result of a flag here? Force them to accept answers? Have a moderator give them a good talking too, suspend them, ban them asking questions?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes you are right, it would not be good to harass any user.

Comment: It's just a support question, no reason to downvote, though I realize the poster didn't use the support tag, fixed now.

Comment: Please don't waste moderator's time flagging users who don't accept answers.  There is nothing moderators can do about this.  Simply avoid these users.

Comment: It is hilarious that many people are finding this Question offensive instead of understanding the nature of the Question.

Comment: It is hilarious that you assume how people feel about this question (I am not offended, I just think it is a bad idea)

Comment: If you look closely at the Question, you will find that I am not trying to suggest a new Feature at all. I was just asking for a way (If there existed). Thanks for your comment, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A user is not required to accept any answer, and flagging a user for not doing that is non-sense.

Instead of flagging, you could simply leave a comment, although you should make sure you are not harassing the user. I usually put in something  like this for new users:

> @user do you need more help? If this or another answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to accept that answer. Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Why is voting important?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: Thanks for your kind response, i got my answer :)