# How to search unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, search, unanswered-questions

It seems that if I want to see unanswered questions, I can only list all unanswered questions, or unanswered questions with a specific tag.

If I try to use the search box in the top-right, it always seems to search ALL questions.

It would be more than useful to be able to search unanswered questions only.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is the `hasaccepted:0` search operator, which will (you guessed it) only show questions without accepted answers.

[Full list of advanced search terms here.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/)

Comment: Too bad this can't more easily be done using the interface. I mean just clicking Unanswered and then searching.

Comment: You can also use `answers:0` to find all questions with 0 answers.

Answer (score 21):

Use `answers:0` as one of the search terms.

There are other search features available, [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: That would search all questions with _no_ answers, which is different than unanswered (no upvoted answers)

Comment: True - but it's at least a start...

Answer (score 5):

I think this could be fixed by making the following search work:

> blahblahblah is:answer hasaccepted:no score:0

currently if you use `is:answer` and `hasaccepted:no` you get questions, instead of answers that are on a question that doesn't have an accepted answer (probably bad behavior)

if you use `is:answer` and `score:0` you get 0-score answers, but the questions they're attached to might have other answers with higher scores (probably good behavior)

but you really want the questions, not the answer, so

My simple idea would be to have a filter `ascore:#` that would filter questions based on the highest answer score, 0 being only 0-score answers, and any other number being the minimum amount of what the answer is scored (just like the current `score:#` filter

So then this search would work:

> blahblahblah hasaccepted:no ascore:0