# Is it possible to search through unanswered questions?

Tags: support, search, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16542/how-to-search-unanswered-questions)

Had a look through questions/faq for this.

Is it possible to search through the set of unanswered questions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered

Comment: only works for tags