# Vote to force-accept an answer for someone else's question

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Community vote for “Accepted Answer” (Rep. >= 5000 only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/community-vote-for-accepted-answer-rep-5000-only)
>   [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)

So I was looking at a couple of answers I had given recently where the OP had commented on my answer with words to the effect of "thanks, you solved my problem!".  But they still failed accepted it as the answer.

I was wondering of the possibility of introducing a feature where, if the questioner fails to accept an answer in a certain length of time, and activity on the question had stopped, we could vote to force-accept the answer for the questioner.

There would have to be a fairly unanimous number of votes from a minimum number of users with high reputation for the answer to be force-accepted.

What do people think? Could this work?