# Vote to Accept Answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)
>   [Community vote for “Accepted Answer” (Rep. >= 5000 only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/community-vote-for-accepted-answer-rep-5000-only)
>   [Vote to force-accept an answer for someone else's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80319/vote-to-force-accept-an-answer-for-someone-elses-question)

I know there has been a lot of discussion on this, but I haven't seen the solution I am presenting now before (despite searching).

There are many questions that either have a good answer that has not been accepted, or the incorrect answer was accepted.

I propose that a system be set up like the 'vote to close' feature.  If multiple users with high reputation vote to accept a (different) answer, it is accepted.  Of course, it can be voted on to un-accept the answer too.

Comment: So I can't earn my Unsung Hero Badge anymore?

Comment: Oh, this solution has been presented before, in a few flavors. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature) [you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/community-vote-for-accepted-answer-rep-5000-only) [go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80319/vote-to-force-accept-an-answer-for-someone-elses-question) ♪

Comment: @Rofl: not unless it gets past everyone else :)

Comment: @Grace: ah.  Okay, so I guess nobody likes the idea.

Comment: Why can't I vote to close my own question?  Oh yeah, not enough rep on meta...

Comment: For the most part. The purpose of "acceptance" is to indicate that the author of the question found it acceptable. Community-voted acceptance, then, would not necessarily reflect this. Thus, acceptance loses its meaning if it isn't with the author's blessing.