# Is it possible for someone with high reputation to mark as answered?

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)

Hi, a lot of questions remain without an answer marked as answer although sometimes there clearly is a correct answer formulated among them.
Is someone with high reputation (or is there a certain privilege) able to mark an answer as being correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, only the person who initially asked the question can "accept" an answer.

See also: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Wouldn't this make sense as a new feature? That way more questions end up marked as answered. It could be for example allowed only when the question is at least 1 month old, so that the person asking the question is first in rank to mark. More rules / restrictions could be implemented..

Comment: @TweeZz: I didn't see the feature-request tag first... But I think this has been discussed before... I think the philosophy behind the "accepted answer" is too personal to let anybody else than the original question asker accept an answer.

Comment: @TweeZz: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/community-vote-for-accepted-answer-rep-5000-only

Comment: I did try to find an existing question first.. I guess my search query was not ok..

Comment: @TweeZz: Don't get too hung up on accepted answers. They're only one very small portion of the site. Upvotes are a perfectly reasonable way for the community to express its collective feeling that an answer is good. In fact, the system considers questions "answered" if they have at least one answer with at least one upvote. There's no real problem to solve here.

Comment: Ok, I got your point, thx!