# User-chosen accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)
>   [Community vote for “Accepted Answer” (Rep. >= 5000 only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/community-vote-for-accepted-answer-rep-5000-only)

I've seem many questions by people with a 4% accept rate that have good, upvoted answers, but no accepted answer. Should the public be able to vote on a best answer if the asker has not accepted an answer within an amount of time (a week, perhaps)?

Comment: This has been proposed and declined before.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Today, no less.

Comment: public only up-vote that's all.

Comment: aaaand there goes my free 100 reputation.

Comment: @tkbx: Next time, search first!

Comment: Only the person who asked the question can decide whether a proposed solution worked for them. It's not our place to say "Here, this is the best answer, it must have solved your problem".

Comment: @tkbx Meta rep is easy come, easy go. If your next question isn't asking for a mandatory downvote explanation, you'll likely regain what you lost today.

Comment: @meagar but it the asker abandons the question, and there's a single correct solution, the answerer (and future searchers) deserve an accept.

Comment: @tkbx No, they don't. Only the person who asked the question is able to state whether an answer solved their problem. End of story. The community can't *tell* somebody that their problem is solved, and that's the whole purpose of accepting answers. Future searches are free to view *all* the answers, and select the one that best solves *their version* of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The public is already able to vote on what it feels is the best answer. They do this by voting on answers.

Most people will take the time to look at the most upvoted answer besides the accepted answer, so it isn't really like the information contained in it is irretrievably obscured to the public eye.

Comment: Re, your comment about "Most People" - is there any data to support that assertion?  (I ask out of curiosity - i.e., is there some set of usage metrics built into SO that I was unaware of?)

Comment: @RobertP No, but the fact that the highest voted answer has been voted the highest indicates that at least as many people as there are votes had to have looked at it.