# Automatically accept answer based on the highest percentage and dynamic reputation in real time?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, reputation, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)

Just suggesting,

Would it be better if SO use Percentage rather than vote count for the Answer?

**Example:** 80 agree and 20 disagree than the percentage of the answer will be 80%.

1. The community would know how much is the rate of acceptance from that answer.
2. If it is based only on the vote count, we all didn't know how many person disagree with it. We only know the total count
3. By using percentage, Everybody know what that value means. Therefore No More FIX ACCEPT of an answer. Because There's no fix answer to that question. Who knows another good question may pop in the future. Agree?

Because of that changes, Some adeptation need to be made.
Especially:

1. The user reputation is also must be computed in real time. User reputation now will depends on the previous acceptance rate multiply by the number of Vote or something like that.
2. But Some drawback perhaps is the Performance, But I believe computation nowadays is cheap.

What do you think?

This is just a suggestion :-)

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear to me. Even the main premise is unclear - what do you mean by "use Percentage rather than vote count for the Answer"?

Comment: I guess the OP means "upvotes/total votes".

Comment: What I mean is that when somebody agree with an answer than the percentage of that answer will be 100%, next user disagree with that answer and it become 50%, next another agree become 66.6%, another agree become 75%. etc...

Comment: Popular answers tend to be correct.  But can be dead wrong on the questions that matter.  Or to put it another way, it if it is that obvious that an answer is correct then the question doesn't make the Internet better.

Comment: This is a duplicate many times over. Look in the "Linked" sidebar of [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669/2509) (and there are some that don't link to it, too).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it wouldn't be better.

The stack exchange Q&A model has two purposes:

1. The ability to ask a question and give answers.  The **original question asker** can select the best answer by **accepting** it. But this is not mandatory.
2. To be a repository of quality questions and answers.  The **community** can rate each question and answer by **voting**. This way the good answers will appear at the top and the "bad" answers are shown lower in line.  The same goes for questions.

Adding another mechanism to accept the answer violates this principle. And that is not good.

And I know that it's frustrating to spend a lot of time to answer a question and not even get a single vote or an accept.  But that's just the way the community works. Just keep up the good work and you will be rewarded at the end.

Comment: But as a community, we're not able to know how many people has disagree with that answer... We only know **Total Vote**

Comment: @Yeo,  if you have enough reputation, you can see both up and downvotes.

Comment: I know about it, we just don't know how many have agreed vs diagree. or else we only see from one side of the score.

I actually wanna Upvote your answer, but my reputation is below the line. Sad...

Comment: @Yeo Why would you need to know how many people disagreed? If The question or answer score is 100, you know that most of the voters agree with it. If it's 0, then either no one is caring about it, or the community is splitted equally. Moreover, when you reach 1k reputation, you can see the actual number of votes if you are really interested in it.

Comment: Opps, I miss. I didn't know that 1k reputation allow me to see the actual vote count... Sorry..