# community tagging

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, accepted-answer, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)

Could you add a feature which would permit to **tag a question as solved if several users flagged one of the response as the solution**? Obviously it would only be available for questions lacking a checked answer and after a certain period of time.

In the unlikely edge case where the user comes back and accept another answer, the answer previously selected by the community would still be tagged but not as prominently as before.

Thresholds would have to be chosen, here's what I would pick: (question) 3 months, (voters) 1000–3000 rep and 4–5 users.

Comment: @random could you remove that status declined plz it's not a duplicate. You added the tag immediately let the users vote and answer?

Comment: @random again it's absolutely not a duplicate of this question, have you read it?

Comment: You want there to be a way for the community to accept an answer on behalf of the OP

Answer (score 5):

That's what votes are for.

The default sorting order is by votes, so the best answers float to the top.

Even if there's no accepted solution, the question is considered "answered" for the purposes of the unanswered tab if an answer has a positive score.

Comment: It _may_ be a score >=2 , instead of "positive score",  I'm not sure. Note that that's only for the unanswered _tab_, `/unanswered` takes into account all posts without a tick.

Comment: Once one answer has a +1 then the whole question is removed from the Unanswered pile @man

Comment: @random isn't there something about a +2 somewhere?

Comment: +2 if you want to win a bounty with a new answer @man

Comment: @random oh right.. Silly me :p

Comment: @kevin what do you do with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7366644/248058) then? It doesn't deserve a +1 and he didn't accept his own answer.