# Can privileged users mark answers as 'Accepted' if the owner only accept the answer in a comment

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)

I've seen that sometimes new users ask a question, and when he gets his answer he Thanks in a comment and goes away, without actually accepting the answer.

My first question is, Is it possible for a privileged user to mark the answer as accepted?

If it is not, should it be? :) Because it actually it's an accepted answer but the guy didn't know how to let the 'site' know that it's accepted.

These kind of question can be sent through the review system so the others can see if the question was answerd, but failed to mark so.

Another idea would be to analyse comments in such a way to detect such comments (i.e: "Thank you, it works well", "perfect", "great", etc) and show a hint at the time of commenting that the user that he should instead/or additionaly accept the answer.

Comment: People are still debating about this issue to this very day. Maybe SO staff will deal with it at some point. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354584/534406