# Abandoned questions

Tags: discussion

When a question gets several answers, upvoted, clearly correct, and the person asking disappears, should we flag for mod attention, is there something the mods do to "teach" the user to not do that?

Comment: Sorry, we don't chain people to the site.

Comment: You folks have several rules about doing stuff over here - like the timing rules, the minimum reputation needed to do stuff etc.. Why not introduce a new one?

Comment: And what new rule would that be?

Comment: an idea: you get a notification after X days if you got over an X number of answers: are you happy with the answer? Yes -> pick it, No-> New notification after X days...

Comment: Users already get notified of new answers when they visit the site. I don't see why would would need to poke them more than that.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos: because you can try and steer peoples actions, but you cannot force them out of *in*-action. **If** you come here and do stuff, do it this way. If you stay away, more power to you.

Comment: If the person disappears, what do you plan to do to bring them back?  Why force them back if they aren't interested?

Comment: IMO comments by answerers/passers-by are sufficient. If the OP doesn't want to play nice, oh well.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I've seen some of the moderators; I suggest going all Sopranos on them.

Comment: I was only thinking something in the likes of negative reputation to that person, and gather all these points in a bonus pool to be distributed to other questions/answers, or an auto-accept of an answer which got over an X number of upvotes. It would be safe to accept an answer with 10,15,20 upvotes when the others are between 0 and 2 for example. At least that's my idea:)

Comment: Example: You abandon a question with decent answers, you get a -10 rep, and before you can keep on asking you need to answer a question yourself..

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos Community accepted answers have been proposed several times before. General consensus is  that that's what upvotes are for.

Comment: @Bart well, ok:) Let's just say one more vote for that then!.. I was thinking about it quite a while and thought I'd raise it over here.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not matter if a user abandons a question. The `content` in the question and the answers matter and not if it is owned by someone or not.

I have come across lot of questions that have been abandoned by users but still have helped others facing the same problem. Sometimes, I leave [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) links on new users' questions to make them realize how to make best use of accepting answers that might help others. You can only do so much to point them in the right direction.

Some users really take good note of the inputs. That really encourages me to think that at least there are users who listen to your inputs and also act upon it.

Answer (score 6):

Nope. Nothing that can, nor should be done. Certainly don't flag for moderator attention. They can't do anything about it.

Comment: This is the best answer. Why isn't it accepted?!

Comment: @BoPersson Abandoned I guess.