# How to deal with abandoned questions?

Tags: discussion

I have some answers to questions kind of abandoned by the author (e.g. the author last login was Feb 19th).

So he didn't upvote, commented or accepted the answer (e.g. [Syntax highlighting on PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462133/syntax-highlighting-on-phpstorm)).

I feel bad about this... anyone else ? What is recommended, just wait ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not much that you can do about it. My practice has always been to post the best possible answer to the problem, maybe some day the user will come back and upvote/accept.

While we'd like the OP to do these things, we want to provide a solution that could be helpful to anyone with the same problem.  It's entirely likely that someone else will search for something similar and your solution will help them.  Then, they will upvote your answer.

I've had answers accepted years after I've posted them.  It happens, and when the late accept happens it's like a nice little gift.

Comment: Great! Nevertheless, some questions are really one-time user-specific problem which does not benefit from time or viewers, it's just that problem which may or not be old and duplicated. But I've had upvotes from old questions as you mentioned, it's great.

Comment: Could it help if the community could make an answer the accepted one in case the question's author hadn't logged in for a long period of time?

Comment: @MarcoA. Proposed many times, and [declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669/259867)

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for linking the post.

Answer (score 6):

If you have an answer post it.

Even if the OP doesn't come back it still might benefit someone else who's experiencing the same problem.

If it's a good answer you'll get up-votes from other members of the community.

Comment: Yes, I always try to write complete answers even when local testing and environment reproduction is needed. Thanks for your thought.

Answer (score 3):

**Good idea:** Provide good detailed answers and they will be noticed by the community eventually. An accepted answer is just 1.5 of an upvote reputation-wise. Upvotes from other users will have much more impact on your reputation (otherwise you'll become an [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero), which isn't bad too).

**Bad idea:** Try nagging users about accepting and upvotes. They'll receive notifications, so if they come back they'll likely notice your messages and act accordingly. Note that moderators don't like these comments.

**Very bad idea:** Never answer questions of new users. They are very likely to be unfamiliar with how Stack Overflow works and will often forget to accept and/or upvote (1-rep users can't even upvote).

Comment: Unsung Hero is a great badge. Regarding the bad idea, I'm just about to answer a question which I polled the user with a comment regarding an incomplete initial answer, and he replied =) It's not that bad. But the 3rd option is not good for me also.