# Unanswered question repeatedly bumped to home page, OP is dormant

Tags: discussion, community-user, bump

As per [my post](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2679/bumping-to-the-home-page/2680) on Software recommendation meta ...

> I am looking at [this recently bumped question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/creating-an-angular-gauge).
>
> It has three good answers (two of them mine :-) but the OP has not
>   upvoted or commented any of them (no one has).
>
> I look at the OP's profile, and see "Last seen Apr 30 '15 at 9:30", so
>   I doubt that he is going to come back and accept an answer.
>
> Maybe a check for this sort of inactivity could be part of the bump
>   process, no matter whether it is manual or automatic.
>
> I do understand that bumping is for inactive questions which did not
>   get much attention, but there is only so much space on the front page,
>   and this question was bumped at the expense of another, which might
>   potentially have been awarded an answer by a poster who is still
>   active.

The question has now been bumped for the second or third time, and will continue to be so unless an answer is accepted - at the expense of other questions.

I would like to explore this a general topic, as I see this sort of thing quite often. Is there no way that a "trusted" user (minim xK rep, or top x%) can say "I have tested this and it answers the question, and mark it as the answer? That would surely be of help to others in future?

I do realize that that might be more realistic on some sites than others, but could we consider it for some?

I have already seen [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature), which basically says "user accepted an answer, but community knows better and wants to mark another answer".

My question says "There is no accepted answer, cannot a reputable member accept one on behalf of the community?", so I don’t think it is a duplicate.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669

Comment: continued:  The comments to that answer are your answer, vote up or down an answer there; after an upvote it won't be bumped, after four downvotes it will be *hidden* but still bumped. --- Do your work (everyone one on that site), vote correctly.

Answer (score 8):

No need to change the system.

The bump will not happen if the question has a negative score or an upvoted answer exists.

If you hate that bump, please take two minutes to evaluate the question/answer already there.

Comment: I'll upvote you, for giving me some good info. What could I do if the only answer(s) were mine? Or if I do not have enough knowledge to upvote? Even if I am in the top few %, I am not knowledgeable on all programming languages or operating systems, for instance?  There are a few questions which I regularly see bumped, no one else is upvoting them, and I don't want to upvote where I am unsure.

Comment: @Mawg I think you answer yourself. If the community cant judge a question/answer, you want the community to accept an answer, is it logical? Never forget the upvote is the way the community choose an answer, the green mark just mean that worked for me from the OP

Comment: Aha, now I see. If I know enough to answer it, just upvoting would prevent it from being bumped again. I can add a comment saying that I have tested the solution and it works. Not quite as good as marking it in some way, but it will work. Thanks.