# Why are old (and abandoned) questions getting bumped to home page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unanswered-questions, community-user, bump

I'm a big fan of WordPress, - and want to help the community by answering questions on the dedicated Stack Exchange. However, - I can see that 'Community' has started to bump old questions to the homepage. Quite a lot, actually. In a way I like that this is done, - however, [many](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130993/list-taxonomy-terms-in-current-post-current-category) [of](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259192/site-redirecting-to-http-example-com-wp-signup-phpnew-example-com) [them](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258352/ajax-the-create-and-edit-post-form-into-lightbox-and-get-results) have two characteristics:

- It's from several years ago, and no correct answer has been marked.
- The author has next-to-no reputation-points, which indicates that this author created an account; asked the question; didn't retrieve the answer they wanted and never did anything else.

This means that even if I came up with the perfect answer to these questions, - there's a good chance that the author will never check it or mark it as a solution.

### Two question-suggestions

1. Wouldn't it be better to say, that questions can only be bumped to the homepage if the author has more than 100 reputation-points, since that would indicate activity from the author?
2. Wouldn't it be good to have a flag-option called 'Deserted by the author', so people finding this question doesn't end up at a dead end?

---

**Update**

I got two downvotes and a condescending comment, so I figured I would elaborate a bit.

I just jumped to page 15 of questions (based on activity), and picked the first 3 questions, that had activity from 'Community':

- [First](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/293033/php-if-user-is-logged-in-on-home-page-redirect)
- [Second](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156392/javascript-onload-calling-a-function-of-a-plugin)
- [Third](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114748/add-select-field-to-media-uploader-that-adds-a-class-to-the-image)

Two of the three ticks both boxes (low-rep author and ancient question). The other ticks just one (ancient question).

**None of the three questions** has gotten extra activity because of this bump.

What am I supposed to do with those questions? I don't like spending my time 'yelling into the void'?

If you downvote, then please leave a comment why.

Comment: "This question has answers that might be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed."

Comment: I might support a request to make the frequency of bumps relative to the number of new questions per day. If there is only say 1 new question per hour (or less, which is roughly where WordPress is at), also having 1 bump per hour can mean 50%+ of your home page is filled with old questions. Although on such sites you really should be taking (or trying to take) an action on the post to stop it from getting bumped.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "Needs focus" because the Feature Request has 2 parts. 1º not bumping based on reputation. 2º not bumping based on last activity by OP. I think an FR should focus on one specific rule, and there are several other FRs about not bumping.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301589

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop the Community user from dredging up old questions over and over?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288652/how-to-stop-the-community-user-from-dredging-up-old-questions-over-and-over) - the comments to that answer are your answer, vote up or down an answer there; after an upvote it won't be bumped, after four downvotes it will be *hidden* but still bumped. --- Do your work (everyone one on that site), vote correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last time those questions were on the front page your community did not give a clear opinion as to whether they were worthy of becoming a permanent part of the Q&A library that your community is building.  If they had, they would no longer be bumped.

When you see them bumped this time you could take one of three main courses of action:

- If you think they should become a permanent Q&A then upvote any answer that you think is useful or, if there is no answer you think useful, then consider providing one or helping someone else to do so by commenting or editing.
- If you think they should NOT become a permanent Q&A then downvote non-useful questions and non-useful answers, or, if you have the privilege, and think that questions are not answer ready, then vote to close them.
- If you do not mind seeing them bumped again at a later date then do nothing.

You say:

> even if I came up with the perfect answer to these questions, -
>   there's a good chance that the author will never check it or mark it
>   as a solution

but you appear not to realize that to stop a question being bumped does not require an answer to be accepted, it just needs an answer with upvotes OR for one to be accepted.

Answer (score 8):

> So what am I supposed to do with those questions?

Well, the message says, "This question has answers that might be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed." So... review it.

> I don't like spending my time 'yelling into the void'?

Then perhaps you have an incorrect understanding of how these sites work.

We're not here to have a discussion. We're here to do Q&A. A question is asked, and answers are provided. It doesn't matter if the person who asked the question *ever* sees the answers. Yes, that means no answer gets accepted, but acceptance is hardly a necessity to the Q&A model.

If you want to answer the question, you may do so. If you think the question needs closing, you may do so. If you just want to ignore it, you can do that too.

The point is to give people an opportunity to see unanswered questions that they may have missed, for which good answers may still be provided for.

Questions are not "abandoned" the way threads can be on a forum. We're providing answers so that the next person with a similar problem can get those answers.

Comment: Problem is that these have already been answered, and the system will keep bumping them because there's no "accepted answer" and none will ever be accepted.

Comment: @JKreft As soon as one of those answers has a net upvote the bumping stops.  I think accepting can stop it too, but that is not required.

Comment: @PolyGeo That doesn't jibe with my recollection of seeing 6-year old questions with multiple +1 answers unaccepted show up on the list. I could be misremembering. Are you 100% certain this is the case?

Comment: @JKreft If you see one like that look for whether it is the result of a merged question. I think that can throw the algorithm. I'm aware of one such question at GIS.